# WORDPRESS meta_query

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать поиск в wordpress более дружелюбным, вот этот код отлично справляется со своей задачей, если имеется переменная $_GET, но в случае его отсутствия просто напросто выдает array(0). Как сделать так что бы поиск осуществлялся только когда есть переменная $_GET?

```
$test = get_posts([
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'Город',
            'value' => $_GET['city']
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'Область',
            'value' => $_GET['address']
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'Режим дня',
            'value' => $_GET['rejim']
        ]
    ]]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните это в if:

```
$meta_query = array();
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'Город',
        'value' => $_GET['city']
    ];
}
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'Область',
        'value' => $_GET['address']
    ];
}
if (isset($_GET['rejim'])) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'Режим дня',
        'value' => $_GET['rejim']
    ];
}

$test = get_posts([
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
    ]);
```

Comment: А что если их множество? Обновил пример.

Comment: обновил ответ...

Comment: Не фильтрует, выдает все записи

Comment: Так работает все же?

Comment: Да всё работает, большое спасибо!

Comment: Возник так же вопрос, можно ли как-то результирующий массив вывести вместо того, что сейчас выводит <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: Оформите новым вопросом поподробнее, завтра подумаю